# Predicate logic: free variable after ∀

Tags: predicate-logic

Consider the formula ∀xα (where x is some variable). Is the occurrence of x which comes just after ∀ considered as a free variable?

Many thanks for your help.

Fish

Comment: NO: $\forall x$ is a complete symbol; you cannot split it. We call *free* the occurences of a variable in a *formula*; $\forall x$ alone is not a formula.

Comment: If I ask it's because I read this in my lecture notes: "Now suppose that α is open. Then the only free variable in ∀xα  is x because we showed that ∀xα is closed". How this can be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

> "Now suppose that $α$ is open. Then the only free variable in $∀xα$ is $x$ because we showed that $∀xα$ is closed"

makes little sense. I think that you have a typo; it must be: "Then the only free variable in $α$ is $x$ because we showed that $∀xα$ is closed."

If $∀xα$ is *closed*, when we remove the leading quantifier $∀x$, what remains is $α$. If now $α$ is *open*, the only possibility is that it contains a *free* occurrence of $x$ that in $∀xα$ has been binded by the quantifier.

If insted we have a free occurrence of $y$ in $α$, also $∀xα$ will have it, and thus also $∀xα$ will be *open*.

---

The [formal definitions](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA60) are :

> all the variables occurring in a term or atomic formula are *free*;
>
> $FV(\lnot \varphi) = FV(\varphi)$;
>
> $FV (\varphi \square \psi) = FV (\varphi) \cup FV (\psi)$, for every binary connective $\square$.
>
> $FV(\forall x \varphi)=FV(\exists x \varphi)= FV(\varphi) \setminus \{ x \}$.
>
> $\varphi$ is called *closed* if $FV(\varphi)= \emptyset$. A closed formula
> is also called a *sentence*. A formula without quantifiers is called open.

Comment: It was definitely a typo!